# MongoDB batch insert not working with java driver

Tags: mongodb

I am trying out mongoDB, here is the code I used to connect and insert records.

```
import com.mongodb.*;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MongoConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("emails");
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long totalRecords = 120L;
        long batchInsert = 0;

        long insertedRecords = 0L;
        List<DBObject> basicDBObjects = new LinkedList<DBObject>();
        while (insertedRecords < totalRecords) {
            System.out.println("adding: "+insertedRecords);

            basicDBObjects.add(new BasicDBObject("email", "amar+" + insertedRecords + "@gmail.com"));
            insertedRecords++;
            batchInsert++;
            if (batchInsert == 5) {
                System.out.println("inserting: "+(insertedRecords-5));
                collection.insert(basicDBObjects);

                System.out.println("Inserted: *******"+insertedRecords);
                //Thread.sleep(200);
                batchInsert = 0;
                basicDBObjects = new LinkedList<DBObject>();
            }
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total time taken :"+((endTime-currentTime)/1000));
        //long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DBCursor email = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("email", "amar+3@gmail.com"));
        int count = email.count();
        System.out.println("count = "+count);
        System.out.println("Total time taken: "+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime));

    }
}
```

I can see the collection with "emails" is created it is shown as part of `show collections`
But when I do `db.mydb.emails.find({})` no result is coming up. I tried re-starting mongo service and even tried `db.dropDatabase()` nothing seems to work. Can anyone point out the issue? FYI inserts over console are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
This code is working with mongoDB Version 2.2.3

So Pleae install this version and check your db

First Perform following command

show dbs
use mydb
show collections

when you perform these three command then you will see list of collection for mydb

then perform 

db.emails.find() which will give you will get Record

Here below i have paste command that i have fire it and check it dear 


C:\dhananjay\mongoDB\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe

MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: test

> show dbs
blog    0.203125GB
course  0.203125GB
local   (empty)
m101    0.203125GB
mydb    0.203125GB
school  0.203125GB
students        0.203125GB
test    0.203125GB

> use mydb
switched to db mydb

> show collections
emails
system.indexes

> db.emails.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a83f22fdb3f79d6a713e71"), "email" : "amar+0@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a83f22fdb3f79d6a713e72"), "email" : "amar+1@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a83f22fdb3f79d6a713e73"), "email" : "amar+2@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a83f22fdb3f79d6a713e74"), "email" : "amar+3@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a83f22fdb3f79d6a713e75"), "email" : "amar+4@gmail.com" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I only changed `MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");` to `Mongo mongo = new Mongo();` and everything worked as you expected.

Which version of mongo driver you are using? I am using mongo 2.9.1 here are the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId> 
<version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>bson</artifactId> 
<version>2.9.1</version> 
</dependency>

Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("example");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("sampleCollection");
        List<DBObject> basicDBObjects = Lists.newArrayList();
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalRecords = 120L;
        long batchInsert = 0;

        long insertedRecords = 0L;
        while (insertedRecords < totalRecords) {
            System.out.println("adding: "+insertedRecords);

            basicDBObjects.add(new BasicDBObject("email", "amar+" + insertedRecords + "@gmail.com"));
            insertedRecords++;
            batchInsert++;
            if (batchInsert == 5) {
                System.out.println("inserting: "+(insertedRecords-5));
                collection.insert(basicDBObjects);

                System.out.println("Inserted: *********"+insertedRecords);
                Thread.sleep(200);
                batchInsert = 0;
                basicDBObjects = Lists.newArrayList();
            }
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total time taken :"+((endTime-currentTime)/1000));
        //long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DBCursor email = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("email", "amar+3@gmail.com"));
        int count = email.count();
        System.out.println("count = "+count);
        System.out.println("Total time taken: "+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime));
```

Comment: tried with 2.10.1 too and it worked again. Are you sure you are checking the right mongo? Can you just change the databaseName and check whether the database is created and so on to ensure that you are connecting to the same mongo that you think you are connecting to =)

Comment: i changed the database names and can see those random dbs were created. But when I try to access the content with db.dbname.emails.find() no results returned.

Comment: Do you mean you checked db.emails.find() and didn't see any results? Because db.dbname.emails is not the right syntax, you should first select the database you wanna work on by `use dbname` command then you can access the collection by `db.collectionName` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually records are getting inserted but I am using wrong commands. Thanks for your time.